# Ruby Dynamically Unpack Rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I want to decide which fields to grab from my database in one spot, in the variable core_game_fields.  This field will always include the `:id`, and then it will include whatever else I decide.  I want to set this field in just one place, and then have the code grab those fields, and unpack it for me into the hash.  Right now this code works, but you can see it means I have to hard code in, and repeat the variables I want to grab 3 times, instead of just 1 time.

```
mh = {}

core_game_fields = [:id, :date, :season, :away_team_id, :home_team_id]
stuff = Game.pluck(*core_game_fields)

stuff.each do |id, date, season, away_team_id, home_team_id|
mh[id] = { :date => date,
           :season => season,
           :away_team_id => away_team_id,
           :home_team_id => home_team_id }
end
```

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: dan@issac:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: Cool, you should have the `to_h` method available on arrays too, which you can use instead of `H[array]`. I'll add that to my answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this (Ruby 1.9.3):

```
mh = stuff.each_with_object({}) do |row,h|
  h[row[0]] = Hash[fields[1, fields.length].zip(row[1, row.length])]
end
```

Here is how it works:

1. `stuff.each_with_object({}) do |row,h|` starts off the `mh` hash, and passes it to each
   iteration of a row in your result set, so that the sub-hash can be added to it. See [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).
2. `h[row[0]]` puts the ID of the row as the key for the sub-hash.
3. `fields[1, fields.length]` slices off all field symbols except the first one, and returns
   them as an array, like `[:date, :season, :away_team_id, :home_team_id]`.
4. The array of field symbols is [zipped together](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) with the row data

   ```
   zip(row[1, row.length])] == zip([date_val, season_val, ...etc])
   ```

   The elements at index 0 are grouped together in a sub-array, then index 1, and so on, until you get `[[:date, date_val], [:season, season_val], ...etc]`.
5. `Hash[Step #4]` converts the array of key/value pairs into an actual hash, which is then assigned to the collection hash `h` at the ID of the row.

If you don't want it all in one line, you could split it up a little like this:

```
sub_fields = fields[1, fields.length]

mh = stuff.each_with_object({}) do |row,h|
  id, rest = row[0], row[1, row.length]
  h[id] = Hash[sub_fields.zip rest]
end
```

Comment: cupcake, any reason not to change each_with_object() to just each() and change h to @mh in the loop?

Comment: @appleLover unless `@mh` is an instance variable of a class, it's generally bad practice to use variables "globally" like that, because it makes your methods tightly coupled with the "globally" modifiable variable, which makes your program harder to test, debug, maintain, and change.